# Connecting to Sybase using Node

Tags: node.js, sybase

How can I connect to Sybase using node.js?

I can see that npm-sybase exists, but how to implement it in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

See top lines in node_modules/sybase/src/sybaseDB.js

```
//FIXME: this is bad should be a way to expose this jar file in the npm package
//so that it can be called properly from parent packages.

var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE1 = process.env.PWD + "/node_modules/sybase/JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";
var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE2 = "./JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";
```

I changed `PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE2` variable to my real path to the requested jar. All work fine after this manipulation.

For example:

```
var PATH_TO_JAVA_BRIDGE2 = "/opt/sybase_exporter/node_modules/sybase/JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **node-sybase** module for this. Just use the command npm install node-sybase. The link of this module is https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sybase.

The Github URL is https://github.com/rodhoward/node-sybase of this npm module. Node.js internally uses java to connect to Sybase. This module makes your task easier to work with.

An example of this is

`const SyBase = require('node-sybase');`
`var sybase = new SyBase([`
`{`
`name: 'main',`
`host: 'localhost',`
`port: '34567',`
`dbname: 'testdb',`
`username: 'test',`
`password: '654321'`
`}`
`]);`

`exports.connect = function (query) {`

`sybase.DBPools.main.execute(`
`query`
`).then(function(res){`
`console.log(res);`
`})`
`.catch(function(err){`
`console.log("in error--->"+err);`
`});`
`}`

Comment: This piece of code connects to the databse, executes the query and keeps connected. It does not show how to disconnect from the database gracefully.

Comment: The Github URL you have given seems to be for another project: https://github.com/rodhoward/node-sybase. What is the Github URL for require('node-sybase') !?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sybase

First you will have to install the npm module

```
npm install sybase --save
```

Then you can connect to sybase like this

```
var Sybase = require('sybase'),
    db = new Sybase('host', port, 'dbName', 'username', 'pw');

db.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);

  db.query('select * from user where user_id = 42', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    console.log(data);

    db.disconnect();

  });
});
```

Comment: It is not working. In that link, it mentions something about configure from GIT. What is it ?

Comment: You can either install from GIT or from npm. The author just offers both options. When you say it is not working. What errors are you getting?

Comment: error : Unable to access the jarfile. ./javasybaseLink/dist/JavasybaseLink.jar.      I have changed the path of jar but still iam getting the same error.

Comment: The .jar file is included in the module so you shouldn't have to change the path. Do you have java installed?

Comment: I have java installed in my system. But still error pops up.                                     spawn called
{ '0': 'java',
  '1':
   [ '-jar',
     './JavaSybaseLink/dist/JavaSybaseLink.jar',
     'host',
     port,
     'db',
     'username',
     'pwd' ] }
[Error: java.sql.SQLException: JZ00L: Login failed.  Examine the SQLWarnings chained to this exception for the reason(s)

Comment: How can I link java to nodejs

Comment: I met the same problem today. I think I got know the reason. If you install with NPM. you will install the old version which will cause above problem. In latest code, which somehow not published, this problem resolved. So you should use git to install this package to get latest build.

Comment: Why is the db.disconnect() called inside the db.connect function? Wouldn't you rather call it after the connect function is complete?

Comment: @Anand db.disconnect() is called in the callback so it only gets called after the query is completed.